# Parent/children relationship in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to know which is the best way to create a two-ways father-children relationship in ruby. For example, the following code:

```
class Bar
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
   end
end

class Foo
  attr_accessor :children
  def initialize(names = %w(john ben maudy))
    @children = names.map{|n| Bar.new(n)}
  end
end
```

With this, it is fairy easy to get from a `Foo` instance to its `Bar` children. But it doesn't have the other way around. For for example:

```
# Instanciates a Foo and get his first son
bar = Foo.new.children.first
# bar can't get to his parent. Essentially, I want 
bar.foo
```

The only idea I had so far is to pass `self` in the `Bar#new` method, to keep the reference on the `bar` objects, but I would like to avoid this. Can you explain me a better way?

**EDIT**

From google I could find the [caller method](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/161460), which gives me the line number. However I was looking for an object reference, a little more abstract than the line number.

**EDIT 2**

You can do this [in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272326/introspect-calling-object)

**EDIT 3**

This [spinoff of pry](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller) seems to be best fit. If anyone can find a way to do this without the gem, I might answer my own question with it.

Comment: Giving `Bar` inheritance from `Foo` may give you the access you want.

Comment: @user2276204 but `Foo` can be `monkey` and bar can be `banana` - the relationship makes sense without intheritance

Comment: You might want to change your terminology/instance variable names.  This has nothing to do with a parent/child relationship in the OO sense and is probably confusing things.

Comment: @JimStewart feel free to edit

Comment: I admit `binding_of_caller` is interesting. But in the end, you'll need to request the caller to return `self`. If your intention is to respect OO paradigm, IMHO it's bad idea to hide an important relation implementation. I'm very curious why don't you want to directly pass `self`?

Comment: @fotanus I've dug into `binding_of_caller`. It needs to [extend the Ruby implementation](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller/tree/master/ext/binding_of_caller) in order to make accessible the callstack. You cannot do it in pure ruby.

Comment: @toch great finding. I guess we will not have a better response so. Maybe you can update your answer and I can pick it?

Comment: @fotanus just updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [strong composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), where the component couldn't be built without a reference to the composite.

That means you need to initialized them with that composite (i.e. pass `self` to the `Bar` instance). This is the way to do it, as you need a reference to the owner. You can possibly set it after, for instance `bar.foo = foo`, but it will implement a looser link, an aggregation.

If we don't receive a reference, we need to find it somewhere. We can make `Foo` a singleton, but it's an anti-pattern as it's like a global variable. `Bar` instances could request to another object what's the reference of their `Foo`. If there is multiple instances of `Foo`, you need to identify them, with an id for instance, but that means `Bar` instances need that id. Then, why not working directly with the reference of the instance of `Foo`?

As conclusion, IMHO the only good solution consists in passing a reference of `Foo` when building a new `Bar` instance.  If the intention is to respect OO paradigm, IMHO it's bad idea to hide that important relation implementation.

Code for the initialization of `Bar` instance with `Foo` instance

```
class Bar # Class of the component
  attr_reader :foo

  # the component must be initialized/built
  # with a ref to the composite foo
  def initialize(name, foo) 
    @name = name
    @foo = foo
   end
end

class Foo # Class of the composite
  attr_reader :children

  def initialize(names = %w(john ben maudy))
    @children = names.map do |n|
      Bar.new(n, self) # pass self to build the component
    end
  end
end

bar = Foo.new.children.first
bar.foo
```

**Update about `binding_of_caller`**

It's an [interesting project](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller) making accessible the callstack. In the current case, it would be used in `Bar::initialized` method to find the composite, who is the caller, and ask it to return `self`.

However, the project needs to [extend the Ruby implementation](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller/tree/master/ext/binding_of_caller). It's then not pure ruby.

Comment: Interesting link, thanks - but the self-as-argument solution, as I stated, I already thought on.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed your last question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: What's your opposition to passing self?  It is the right and best way to model this sort of relationship.

Comment: @toch I don't have an answer with that. Yet I don't think this invalidates the question - maybe if we don't had to do this, we would feel happier?

Comment: @fotanus with pleasure. I commented your question, I'm very curious about your reasons.

Comment: @toch I'm just an unsatisfied guy with toy projects.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should just pass foos into Bar's constructor like:

```
class Bar
  def initialize(name, parent)
    @name = name
    @parent = parent
   end
end

class Foo
  attr_accessor :children
  def initialize(names = %w(john ben maudy))
    @children = names.map{|n| Bar.new(n, self)}
  end
end
```

This way each bar will have a reference to the foo that created it.

If you really don't want to pass foo into bar's constructor, you could also do something like the following, but I don't think it gains you much.

```
class Bar
  attr_accessor :foo
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
   end
end

class Foo
  attr_accessor :children
  def initialize(names = %w(john ben maudy))
    @children = names.map{|n| Bar.new(n)}
  end
  def get_nth_child(n)
    bar = @children[n]
    bar.foo = self
    bar
  end
end
```

and then you access your original foo like:

```
Foo.new.get_nth_child(1).foo
```

Comment: Read my question again: `The only idea I had so far is to pass self in the Bar#new method, to keep the reference on the bar objects, but it is ugly.`

Comment: @fotanus see my edit. It will work, but I think the first option is better.

Comment: Interesting, maybe better overwriting the `[]` operator? This is not exactly what I was looking for, but is very interesting anyway. +1 for creativity.