# Access instance object attributes from instance.stack()

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something really ugly and need help.
From some method, I'm trying to analyze the stack and identify which class called this method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497683/can-python-determine-the-class-of-a-object-accessing-a-method).
But I want to go one step further and update some attribute of the instance of the class that called my method.

Example:

```
class A(object):
    self.a

    def some_func():
        analyze()

def analyze():
    frm = inspect.stack()[1]
    obj = find_obj_of_frm_by_magic(frm)
    obj.a = 1
```

Comment: What issues are you facing right now?

Comment: I can access the class, but not the instance...

Comment: Is that the actual code? Because as is there are a few syntax errors.

Comment: I'm going to post an answer to see if I am on the right track with what you are looking for. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use your "find_obj_of_frm_by_magic" method which I am assuming is the logic in that post you linked. I tried doing this instead, however I explicitly used the class and I was able to modify the instance doing the following.

I used the `setattr` method to add an attribute to the class. The only difference is that I am using the class explicitly.

```
class A(object):
    a = ""

    def some_func(self):
        analyze()

def analyze():
    frm = inspect.stack()[1]
    setattr(frm[0].f_globals.get('A'), 'stuff', 'boo')

a = A()
a.some_func()
# will output boo
print(a.stuff)
```